# How can i convert SqlNode expression(not query!) to RelNode?

Tags: sql, apache-calcite

I recently start learning Calcite(1.8.0) and i have following use case:

i need to transform a list of strings like "`SUM(x) / SUM(y) as myRatio`", "`MAX(z) as maxZ`" or "`CASE WHEN …`” to `AggCall`s and use it in `RelBuilder` later.

So seems like i should do following: convert string -> sql node -> rel node. I converted String to SqlNode using `SqlParser.parseExpression` and tried `Planner.rel(sqlNode)` to convert SqlNode to RelNode but no luck. Also tried to create `SqlToRelConverter` myself, but cannot find out how to create validator, catalog reader and cluster from config created with just JdbcSchema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because you're dealing with calls to aggregate functions, and these are not ordinary expressions. Note that an `AggCall`, used by `RelBuilder` is neither a `SqlNode` nor a `RexNode`.

So, the simplest thing is probably to convert your expression string into a valid query string. E.g. "`SUM(x) / SUM(y) as myRatio"`" becomes "`SELECT SUM(x) / SUM(y) as myRatio FROM (VALUES (0, 0)) AS t(x, y)`". Then parse this and convert it to `RelNode`. `PlannerTest.testParseAndConvert` does exactly this; it uses only a few lines of code, so you could copy-paste from that method.

Comment: thanks! so i can convert `SUM(x) / SUM(y) as myRatio` to `RelNode`, but how can i add one more expression to it? for example, `SUM(x) as X`. I am expecting to extract `SUM(x) / SUM(y) as myRatio` part from `RelNode` and add it to a builder and do the same for `SUM(x) as X`. Not sure if it's possible...

Comment: You can convert `SELECT SUM(x) / SUM(y) as myRatio, SUM(x) AS x, SUM(y) AS y FROM (VALUES (0, 0)) AS t(x, y)` the same way as the previous query.

You'll end up with an `Aggregate` to compute the sums, then a `Project` that computes `$0  / $1 as myRatio, $0 as x, $1 as y`.

Or, if you're using `RelBuilder`, you can call `RelBuilder.aggregate()` to create `SUM(x)` and `SUM(y)`, then call `RelBuilder.project()` to project `$0  / $1 as myRatio, $0 as x, $1 as y`.